# Time traveling princess Alicia

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a book I think was written in the 80s. It was named after a character in it who travels back in time, almost gets burned as a witch, but the Prince falls in love with her. Apparently she can travel back and forth to any time she wants, including her mom.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions.

Comment: Some possible matches here; https://www.google.co.uk/search?ie=UTF-8&client=ms-android-hms-tef-gb&source=android-browser&q=time+travel+%22princess+alicia%22&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=VqfPWa60C5PS8Aft6angDA

Comment: Is Princess Alicia the name of the character? Same as your user name?

Comment: One of these, perhaps; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=Alicia&type=Fiction+Titles if the title is the Princesses name...